# Paladins API issue to create session

Tags: php, api

I would like to use Paladins API to make a stats website but when I send an HTTP request to create a session I get this error as answere from the API:

`string(113) "{"ret_msg":"Exception while processing: Invalid date format","session_id":"","timestamp":"7\/6\/2022 3:49:56 PM"}"`

The problem seems to be timestamp parameter. For sure I looked at [API documentation](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1OFS-3ocSx-1Rvg4afAnEHlT3917MAK_6eJTR6rzr-BM/edit) but no further information on what to put as timestamp:

[image]

I've tried several timestamp but still stucked here. Note that I can successfully ping the API so that's not a server issue:
`string(99) ""PaladinsAPI (ver 0.0.41.17634) [PATCH - 5.4] - Ping successful. Server Date:7\/6\/2022 4:05:18 PM""`

Here is my code:

```
$ping = file_get_contents("https://api.paladins.com/paladinsapi.svc/pingJson");
var_dump($ping);

$createSession = file_get_contents("https://api.paladins.com/paladinsapi.svc/createsessionJson/myDevId/myDevPaswd/".strval(time()));
var_dump($createSession);
```

So here is my question: do someone already used this API and/or know what's wrong with my code? Or do someone know what to put as timestamp parameter to make my request work?

Comment: Note : for people using this API, server compare signature and timestamp based on UTC time so use `gmdate("YmdHis")` instead of `date("YmdHis")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I looked at [API documentation](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1OFS-3ocSx-1Rvg4afAnEHlT3917MAK_6eJTR6rzr-BM/edit) but no further information on what to put as timestamp

Are you sure about this? The example API call included on page 18 of this document shows explicitly how this is expected to be formatted, which is `yyyyMMddHHmmss`.

Using the format identifiers on [PHP: DateTime::format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php), you could do something along the lines of:

```
$api = file_get_contents("https://api.paladins.com/paladinsapi.svc/createsessionJson/myDevID/myDevPaswd/".date("YmdHis"));
```

Comment: oh yes thank you ! I don't understand how but I didnt even saw it, sorry for time waste.